# Restlet brings back null in android but not Java SE

Tags: android, restlet

I already have a solution - but would love an explanation why

Problem
When doing a Restlet GET in Android - I great fine results with basic types (long)  but I also have an Object with a ListArray being returned and that is always null.
Works fine in a JAVA SE test app

I read the forums and saw someone mention including

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredConverters().add(new JacksonConverter());
```

This works for me ! Great - but why ? I don't want my app to flake out on something else and not know how to understand and solve it.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that Android APK files excludes the META-INF/services directories used to automatically detect available converters in Restlet.

Hence, you need to manually register them.